# in corona using sprites in flipbook

Tags: coronasdk

```
local Flipbook = `enter code here`require 'flipbook'

local myFirstFlipbook = Flipbook:newFlipbook("background_back.png", "mainshadow.png", "newshadow.png", "curlshadow.png" )
myFirstFlipbook:addPage( "backgroundA.png" )
myFirstFlipbook:addPage( "backgroundB.png" )
myFirstFlipbook:addPage( "backgroundC.png" )
```

Used the above code to implement the page curling effect

I want to add a sprite in one of the pages such that the sprite also curls as the page , and I am facing lots of issues implementing it

If anyone could guide me through this... would be a great help.

Comment: What issues are you facing?  More details would be helpful

Comment: Have you looked at this example ? http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/flipbook-module-realistic-page-curling-effect There is also a link to an example of github.